# Перегрузка метода в зависимости от длины передаваемого массива

Tags: java

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы метод выполнялся по-разному в зависимости от длины передаваемого массива (0, 1, 2 или 3)? Причем решить эту задачу с помощью перегрузки.

Т.е. в каждом случае мы фактически передаем разное количество параметров от 0 до 3.

Я передаю массив, длина которого варьируется от 0 (`null`) до 3 элементов. В зависимости от длины передаваемого массива метод немного варьируется.

Пока я придумал по-дурацки:

```
if (currOper.length == 0) {
    expVal = expValDet();
}
if (currOper.length == 1) {
    expVal = expValDet(currOper[0]);
}
if (currOper.length == 2) {
    expVal = expValDet(currOper[0], currOper[1]);
}
```

Comment: так `количество параметров от 0 до 3-х` или `длины передаваемого массива 0 1 2 3` ? Может поконкретнее?

Comment: скорее всего имеется в виду параметры массива, не правильно выразился автор.

Comment: Я немного добавил конкретики в вопросе.

Comment: Знаете, я согласен с @АлексейШиманский по поводу XY-проблемы: в реальных задачах на производстве такая задача бы вам не встретилась, а ваша задача выглядит как слишком учебная, тренировочная. Часто swich (ваши несколько if - это switch) переделывают в классы см. [например тут](https://refactoring.guru/ru/smells/switch-statements) но это неоднозначная практика, да и ну не делают это на базе именно длины массива.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Java нет возможности в параметрах метода указать, что массив должен быть указанной длины. Поэтому не получится перегрузить метод, указав в перегрузке массив другой длины.

Как вариант, можно элементы массива передавать по отдельности:

```
public void method(int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4) { ... }

public void method(int i1, int i2, int i3) { ... }
```

Также можно не перегружать метод, а создать разные методы:

```
public void methodFour(int[] data) { ... }

public void methodThree(int[] data) { ... }
```

Однако в обоих вариантах вам всё равно придётся проверять длину массива и вызывать тот или иной метод в `if-else` или `switch-case`.

Comment: Жаль. В обоих случаях код выглядит некрасиво. В любом случае спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @lmihael мне вот лично кажется что это [проблема XY](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/709/191482)

Comment: @lmihael на здоровье. Да, некрасиво. Однако вы можете сделать эти методы `private`, а внешнему миру показывать только один вариант `public void method(int[] array)`, внутри которого уже вызывать нужный `private` метод.

Comment: В смысле, некрасиво? А пачка "перегруженных" методов чем бы от этого отличалась?

Comment: @vp_arth в конечном счете, ни один из вариантов, включая пачку перегрузок, изяществом не отличается. Но, конечно, это не отменяет того факта, что подобные конструкции используются при небольшом количестве параметров.